# Creating axis with custom (range) values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to add a xAxis with custom values to my density plot (see Screenshot).

[image: Adding Custom x-Axis]

First density "violin" stands for "0-50", second for "51-100", third for "101-150" ... and seventh density for "301-350" passengers. It should look similar to what is shown in the following edited screenshot.

[image]

As I am a rookie in d3 and javascript I would appreciate detailed answers.
I am working with d3.js (v4).

Here is my current code:

```
function addViolin(svg, dataOfBin, heightPlot, widthPlot, domain, imposeMax, violinColor){


        var data = d3.histogram()
                    .thresholds(resolution)
                    (dataOfBin);

        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range([widthPlot/2, 0])
                    .domain([0, Math.max(imposeMax, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.length; }))]);

        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range([heightPlot, 0])
                    .domain(domain)
                    .nice();


        var area = d3.area()
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal)
            .x(function(d) {
                   if(interpolation=="step-before")
                        return x(d.x1/2)
                   return x(d.x);
                })
            .y0(widthPlot/2)
            .y1(function(d) { return y(d.length); });


        var line=d3.line()
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal)
            .x(function(d) {
                   if(interpolation=="step-before")
                        return x(d.x1/2)
                   return x(d.x);
                })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.length); });

        var gPlus=svg.append("g")
        var gMinus=svg.append("g")

        gPlus.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "area")
          .attr("d", area)
          .style("fill", violinColor);

        gPlus.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "violin")
          .attr("d", line)
          .style("stroke", violinColor);


        gMinus.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "area")
          .attr("d", area)
          .style("fill", violinColor);

         gMinus.append("path")
           .datum(data)
           .attr("class", "violin")
           .attr("d", line)
           .style("stroke", violinColor);

        gPlus.attr("transform", "rotate(90,0,0)  translate(0,-"+widthPlot+")");//translate(0,-200)");

        gMinus.attr("transform", "rotate(90,0,0) scale(1,-1)");

}

function addBoxPlot(svg, dataOfBin, heightPlot, widthPlot, domain, boxPlotWidth, boxColor, boxInsideColor){
}

var marginPlot={top:10, bottom:0, left:30, right:10};

var widthPlot=400;
var heightPlot=220;
var boxWidth=44;
var boxSpacing=10;

var resolution=1000;
var d3ObjId="svgElement1";
var interpolation='step-before';


function showView3(data){
    var regionChart = document.getElementById("view3Diagram");
    if(regionChart != null){
        regionChart.innerHTML = "";
    }


    var domain=[0, 370];
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([heightPlot-marginPlot.bottom, marginPlot.top])
                .domain(domain);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                    .scale(y)
                    .ticks(5)
                    .tickSize(5,0,5);


    var svg = d3.select("div#view3Diagram")
                .append("div")
                .classed("svg-container2", true)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 430 430")
                .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);


    svg.append("line")
        .attr("class", "boxplot")
        .attr("x1", marginPlot.left)
        .attr("x2", widthPlot-marginPlot.right)
        .attr("y1", y(0))
        .attr("y2", y(0));

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        data[i].Haltezeiten=data[i].Haltezeiten.sort(d3.ascending)
        var g=svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+(i*(boxWidth+boxSpacing)+marginPlot.left)+",0)");
        addViolin(g, data[i].Haltezeiten, heightPlot, boxWidth, domain, 0.25, "#424242");
        addBoxPlot(g, data[i].Haltezeiten, heightPlot, boxWidth, domain, .15, "black", "white");

    }

    svg.append("g")
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .attr("transform", "translate("+marginPlot.left+",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

}
```

Comment: If you don't show us the scale you're using and your current axis generator, it will be very hard to provide an answer that suits you.

Comment: Thanks for your information Gerardo. I've added my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you requested, I'll write a detailed explanation in this answer (however, this code doesn't seem the work of a rookie...).

As we can see, you use a `for` loop...

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
```

... to create the `<g>` elements and, inside each one of them, the violin plots.

So, the most important thing here is `data.length`. We'll use that to set the domain or our point scale, which will be fundamental for customizing the axis' ticks later. Follow me:

If you pass `d3.range(data.length)` as the domain of the scale, you'll have an array of numbers with the same length of `data.length`. For instance, if `data.length` is 7, this is the result of `d3.range(data.length)`:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Then, with this domain, we can create a customization in the axis using `tickFormat`. For that, I'm going to set a variable named `steps`, which says what's the gap between the values in the first tick. In your example:

```
var steps = 50;
```

With the domain and the `step` set, this is the math in the `tickFormat`:

```
.tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return i ? (d * steps) + 1 + " - " + (d * steps + steps) 
    : (d * steps) + " - " + (d * steps + steps);
});
```

In case you don't know, this is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's basically:

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

If `condition` is true, `expr1` is executed, otherwise `expr2` is executed.

Make sure that you pass the same range to the scale, and that you translate it accordingly.

Here is the running demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var steps = 50;
var data = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"];
var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .range([20, 470])
  .domain(d3.range(data.length));
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return i ? (d * steps) + 1 + " - " + (d * steps + steps) : (d * steps) + " - " + (d * steps + steps);
  });
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```